# How do I remove a file extension in the HTML HEAD metadata for canonical URLs?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, canonical-link

I have a website that requires files to be served without the file extension. For example, the URL `http://www.example.com/foo.php` should be accessible as simply `http://www.example.com/foo`.

However, please forgive me as I am a novice at PHP, but I would also like the `<link rel="canonical ...>` in the HTML file's HEAD metadata to show this too.

So far, I have got:

`<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">`

This brings up the full URL, including the file extension.

Is there anybody out there with a it more PHP knowledge than myself that can modify that above line of code to exclude the file extension?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the extension using str_replace

```
$string_with_extension = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$extension = ".php";

$new_string = str_replace($extension,"",$string_with_extension);
```

Simply, your just replacing the extension with "" or nothing resulting to your desired url.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $new_string; ?>">
```